# Change key bindings (keyboard shortcuts) in Firefox 57

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-quantum

Since the Firefox 57 (Quantum) update all AddOns which allowed to change key bindings in Firefox seemed to have stopped working/being supported.

Is there a method to change the default key bindings in Firefox Quantum?

Comment: There is a bug for this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303384

Answer (score 20):

There is a way.  It's not super official, but basically you can unpack `browser/omni.ja`, edit the keybindings in `chrome/browser/content/browser/browser.xul`, repack it, delete startup cache and it will work.

Alternatively, you can compile your own firefox and then you don't need to unpack the binary, if you consider unpacking and repacking more hacky, than building.

Another advantage of building is that you can store your modifications on top of the official sources in git and always rebase, like I do here: https://github.com/errge/gecko-dev/tree/gregzilla-patched-20181223

I advise you to first start with the binary option, because you will have working keyboard shortcuts in 20 minutes, instead of just being at the start of the mercurial clone procedure :)

Both of these methods are independent of any extensions/webextensions and will ALWAYS work, even in the location bar and even on protected pages (as you asked in the comments).  So they will work better than remapping webextensions.

I have an article written up with all the details that may interest you: https://github.com/nilcons/firefox-hacks

If you have more questions, please report issues on github.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Without actually providing the steps one must take, there is no answer in this post. Please [edit] your post to include this information, including the essential content of linked material.

Comment: Hey, thanks you! How this will effect the updates firefox gets? Do I have to rebuilr + reinstall firefox after each update? Or can I somehow setup a different update channel so it will fetch from my travis builds for example? That way I could mostly automate the process I hope.

Comment: If you are just after the keybindings (and not interested in compiling your own for other reasons), then I would use this part of the article: https://github.com/nilcons/firefox-hacks#binary-hacking-automated  So basically I have this script as "patch-the-fox" and whenever I notice that firefox is not working correctly, I just start a shell, and run "patch-the-fox" and restart.  Then it's good again for 2-3 weeks.

Comment: `browser.xul` was renamed to `browser.xhtml`: https://www.userchrome.org/firefox-changes-userchrome-css.html#fx69

Comment: there is no `browser.xul` file and no configuration possiblity for `quitApplicationCmd` in `browser.xhtml`

Comment: @banan3'14 Hi there, I don't know about quitApplicationCmd, but the whole concept is still valid, I updated my article to contain the new solution (patch-the-fox): https://github.com/nilcons/firefox-hacks#update-2020-01-04-still-using-this-with-minor-tweaks

Comment: I am looking to specifically disable the ctrl-shift-c shortcut to bring up the inspector, but I couldn't find it in `browser.xhtml` following your method.  As a bonus side benefit, I would like to add shortcuts for ctrl-shift-c and ctrl-shift-v for copy/paste if possible.  (Copy anywhere, paste in the URL/search bar.)  Any thoughts?  I will post a separate question unless it can easily be answered here.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 22, /usr/lib/firefox/browser has moved into /snap, which is a read-only file system.  So this patching no longer works.

Answer (score 13):

You can change key bindings in Firefox with [AutoConfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig), without having to unpack and modify the Firefox binary.

**Create a `config-prefs.js` and `config.js` file:**

on Windows:

- `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\config-prefs.js`
- `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\config.js`

on macOS:

- `Firefox.app\Contents\Resources\config.js`
- `Firefox.app\Contents\Resources\defaults\pref\config-prefs.js`

on Linux:

- `/usr/lib/firefox/config.js`
- `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/config-prefs.js`

with the following content:

**`config-prefs.js`:**

```js
pref("general.config.filename", "config.js");    
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);  
pref("general.config.sandbox_enabled", false);
```

**`config.js`:**

```js
try {
  let { classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, manager: Cm  } = Components;
  const Services = globalThis.Services;
  const {SessionStore} = Components.utils.import('resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionStore.jsm');
  function ConfigJS() { Services.obs.addObserver(this, 'chrome-document-global-created', false); }
  ConfigJS.prototype = {
    observe: function (aSubject) { aSubject.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this, {once: true}); },
    handleEvent: function (aEvent) {
      let document = aEvent.originalTarget; let window = document.defaultView; let location = window.location;
      if (/^(chrome:(?!\/\/(global\/content\/commonDialog|browser\/content\/webext-panels)\.x?html)|about:(?!blank))/i.test(location.href)) {
        if (window._gBrowser) {

          // Place your keyboard shortcut changes here
          // ...
          // ...


        }
      }
    }
  };
  if (!Services.appinfo.inSafeMode) { new ConfigJS(); }
} catch(ex) {};
```

After modifying these files, you always have to go to `about:support` and run `Clear startup cache`, to restart the browser with the new config.

**Some examples what you can do:**

*Put these snippets into `config.js`, where I wrote `Place your keyboard shortcut changes here`.*

Remove an existing keyboard shortcut

```js
// remove Ctrl-Shift-X, so that I can map it to 1Password in the 1Password app later
let keySwitchDirection = window.document.getElementById('key_switchTextDirection');
keySwitchDirection.remove();
```

Change an existing keyboard shortcut

```js
// remap Ctrl-J to downloads (removing it from focusing the browser bar)
let search2 = window.document.getElementById('key_search2')
search2.remove();
let openDownloads = window.document.getElementById('key_openDownloads')
openDownloads.setAttribute("modifiers", "accel");
openDownloads.setAttribute("key", "J");
```

Create a new keyboard shortcut

```js
// create keyboard shortcut to Toolbar > Settings with Ctrl-,
let settingsKey = window.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'key');
settingsKey.setAttribute("id", "key_Settings");
settingsKey.setAttribute("modifiers", "accel,shift");
settingsKey.setAttribute("key", "U");
settingsKey.setAttribute("oncommand", "openPreferences()");
settingsKey.addEventListener('command', this, false);
mainKeyset.appendChild(settingsKey);
```

Something completely custom. (*Firefox introduced the Shift-Ctrl-T as an universal undo ([change set](https://a44656c2ad83d278286aa51507864e53a3911df3)), so the example here is not necessary anymore. I'll leave it here to serve as an example for other customizations.*)

```js
// make Ctrl-Shift-T reopen last tab OR last window, depending on which one was closed last
let undoCloseTabKey = window.document.getElementById('key_undoCloseTab');
undoCloseTabKey.removeAttribute('command');
undoCloseTabKey.setAttribute('oncommand', 'undoCloseLastClosedTabOrWindow()');
undoCloseTabKey.addEventListener('command', this, false);

window.undoCloseLastClosedTabOrWindow = function() {
  // don't have any tabs to restore
  if (SessionStore.getClosedTabCount(window) == 0) {
    // we don't need to worry whether there are any windows to restore - undoCloseWindow does that for us
    window.undoCloseWindow();
  }

  // don't have any windows to restore
  else if (SessionStore.getClosedWindowCount() == 0) {
    // we don't need to worry whether there are any tabs to restore - undoCloseTab does that for us
    window.undoCloseTab();
  }

  // restore whichever was closed more recently
  else if (SessionStore.getClosedTabData(window)[0].closedAt > SessionStore.getClosedWindowData()[0].closedAt) {
    window.undoCloseTab();
  } else {
    window.undoCloseWindow();
  }
}
```

**Instructions:**

To find existing keyboard shortcuts:

- Hamburger menu > More Tools > Browser Toolbox
- In the Inspector, search for `#mainKeyset`
- There, you see all assigned keyboard shortcuts

To find menu actions that you can trigger with keyboard shortcuts

- Hamburger menu > More Tools > Browser Toolbox
- Use the Inspector to find the element that you want to trigger with a keyboard shortcut, for example `appMenu-settings-button`
- Take the `oncommand` attribute from the menu item, and use it as `oncommand` attribute for the key tag

or

- Use the Inspector, search for `#mainCommandSet`
- and take the commands's `id`, and use it as `command` (not `oncommand`) attribute for the key tag.

Defining keyboard shortcuts:

- specify modifiers with the `modifiers` attribute. You can use `accel` (for Ctrl), `shift` and `alt`
- specify the key itself with the `key` attribute

Source for all of this: [Reddit, u/aveyo, Restore Ctrl+Shift+B = Library by setting config.js](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/kilmm2/restore_ctrlshiftb_library_by_setting_configjs/)

More details: [Firefox Keyboard Shortcuts (Web Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20191007211804/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Tutorial/Keyboard_Shortcuts)

Comment: This answer is exceptionally well written, and seems to describe the best method for compatibility and long-term use. This is not user friendly though, the price to pay for Mozilla not providing this elementary function, a choice I cannot understand.

Comment: Note: for Firefox 117, the script needs to be slightly updated. `toolkit/modules/Services.jsm` was removed in Firefox 117 ([changelog](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/a920ea193e291fa023837bed7b86f6b74ed06e51))

Comment: in my case the config.js file SHALL start with a commented line otherwise FF fails at loading it

Comment: I'm new here, but, using a modern version of Firefox, searching for #mainKeyset using the Inspector tab of the Web Developer Tools doesn't return anything. Anyone know of a way to do this using newer Firefox versions? Thank you!

Comment: @Bink: it's still the same procedure on the currently latest stable version of Firefox (122.0). Make sure you start the _Browser Toolbox_ (in Hamburger menu > More Tools > Browser Toolbox), and not the _Web Developer Tools_.

Comment: @BenediktKöppel Thanks for chiming back! Looks like the Browser Toolbox does not appear by default and appears to need devtools.chrome.enabled and devtools.debugger.remote-enabled to be set to true for it to appear.

Answer (score 5):

If you use macOS, you can customize any app’s shortcuts as long as they appear in the application menus. Instructions for macOS 13+

> 1. On your Mac, choose  menu  > ***System Settings***, click ***Keyboard***  in the sidebar (you may need to scroll down), then click ***Keyboard Shortcuts*** on the right.
> 2. Select ***App Shortcuts*** on the left, click the Add button, click the ***Application*** pop-up menu, then choose a specific app or ***All Applications***.
> 3. In the ***Menu Title*** field, type the menu command for which you want to create a shortcut, exactly as the command appears in the app

More details on Apple’s site: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac

Answer (score 4):

Here's another working example with the latest version of Firefox at the time of this writing (113.0) based on [@Benedikt Köppel's](https://superuser.com/a/1747680/1802107) answer. For debugging it can be helpful to use the function `Services.prompt.alert(null, "Title", "Message")` (mentioned [here](https://mike.kaply.com/2012/03/22/customizing-firefox-advanced-autoconfig-files/)), in addition to logs which can be found under Tools > Browser Tools > Browser Toolbox > Console with `Error` and `Warnings` enabled on the top right.

###### firefox.cfg

```javascript
// -*- mode: javascript; -*- vim: set ft=javascript:
// See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig
"use strict";

(() => {
  if (Services.appinfo.inSafeMode) {
    return;
  }

  const addressPattern = new RegExp(
    "^(chrome:(?!//(global/content/commonDialog)\\.xhtml)|about:(?!blank))"
  );

  Services.obs.addObserver(subject => {
    const namespaceID =
      "autoconfig_" + subject.crypto.randomUUID().replaceAll("-", "_");
    subject.addEventListener(
      "DOMContentLoaded",
      event => {
        const document = event.originalTarget;
        const window = document.defaultView;
        if (!addressPattern.test(window.location.href)) {
          return;
        }

        // To find a key code ID, go to Tools > Browser Toolbox in Firefox and
        // click on the web inspector, then search for "keycode". Or go to this
        // URL view-source:chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml
        const keyReloadSkipCache = document.getElementById(
          "key_reload_skip_cache"
        );
        keyReloadSkipCache?.setAttribute("modifiers", "accel,alt");

        const keyToggleReaderMode = document.getElementById(
          "key_toggleReaderMode"
        );
        keyToggleReaderMode?.setAttribute("modifiers", "accel,shift");

        const keyScreenshot = document.getElementById("key_screenshot");
        keyScreenshot?.setAttribute("modifiers", "accel,shift,alt");

        const keyUndoCloseTab = document.getElementById("key_undoCloseTab");
        keyUndoCloseTab?.setAttribute("modifiers", "accel,shift");
        keyUndoCloseTab?.setAttribute("key", "T");

        const keyUndoCloseWindow = document.getElementById(
          "key_undoCloseWindow"
        );
        keyUndoCloseWindow?.setAttribute("modifiers", "accel,control,shift");
        keyUndoCloseWindow?.setAttribute("key", "T");

        const keyPrivateBrowsing = document.getElementById(
          "key_privatebrowsing"
        );
        keyPrivateBrowsing?.setAttribute("key", "N");

        // Prefer Unclutter over default reader view.
        // https://unclutter.lindylearn.io
        const toggleUnclutterCommand = namespaceID + "_toggleUnclutter";
        window[toggleUnclutterCommand] = () => {
          // From about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox > Unclutter >
          // Extension ID.
          const extensionID = "8f8c4c52-216c-4c6f-aae0-c214a870d9d9";
          const keyUnclutter = window.document.querySelector(
            `#ext-keyset-id-_${extensionID}_ > key`
          );
          keyUnclutter?.dispatchEvent(new window.CustomEvent("command"));
        };

        const readerModeButton = document.getElementById("reader-mode-button");
        readerModeButton?.setAttribute(
          "onclick",
          toggleUnclutterCommand + "();"
        );
        const readerViewCommand = document.getElementById("View:ReaderView");
        readerViewCommand?.setAttribute(
          "oncommand",
          toggleUnclutterCommand + "();"
        );
      },
      { once: true }
    );
  }, "chrome-document-global-created");
})();
```

###### defaults/pref/autoconfig.js

```javascript
// See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig
pref("general.config.filename", "firefox.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.sandbox_enabled", false);
```

I recommend running `firefox.cfg` (or `config.js` in the above answer) against [Mozilla's ESLint plugin](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/lint/linters/eslint-plugin-mozilla.html) which shows warnings I could not find documented anywhere else. E.g., it gives this error when using `Components.utils.import`:

```
error  Please use ChromeUtils.import instead of Cu.import  mozilla/use-chromeutils-import
error  Use Cu rather than Components.utils                 mozilla/use-cc-etc
```

It can be installed via `npm install eslint-plugin-mozilla --save-dev`.

Here's an example `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:mozilla/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "mozilla"
  ]
}
```

### macOS Persistent Installation

Unfortunately, since on macOS these files must be placed in the application bundle, they can get wiped after updates. This can be worked around by setting up a path watcher script using either Launchd or [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/).

###### firefox_apply_autoconfig

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit -o nounset

FIREFOX_PATH="/Applications/Firefox.app"
FIREFOX_RESOURCES_PATH="$FIREFOX_PATH/Contents/Resources"

# Path to directory containing firefox.cfg and `defaults/autoconfig.js` (or
# equivalent).
AUTOCONFIG_DIR="/patch/to/autoconfig"

main() (
    if [ ! -d "$FIREFOX_PATH" ]; then
        echo "Application does not exist at $FIREFOX_PATH; aborting."
        exit 1
    fi

    cd "$FIREFOX_RESOURCES_PATH"
    mkdir -p ./defaults/pref
    cd "$AUTOCONFIG_DIR"
    find . -type f | while read -r file; do
        relpath="$(echo "$file" | cut -c3-)"
        target="$FIREFOX_RESOURCES_PATH/$relpath"
        source="$(realpath "$file")"
        rsync --archive "$source" "$target"
    done

    # Avoid macOS sandbox warning when Firefox is reinstalled about the app
    # bundle being modified.
    xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Firefox.app

    echo "Installed Firefox autoconfig files."
)

main
```

###### Launchd (Option 1)

###### com.superuser.firefox-apply-autoconfig.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.superuser.firefox-apply-autoconfig</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/username/Library/Application Support/com.superuser.launchd/firefox_apply_autoconfig</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/username/Library/Application Support/com.superuser.launchd/firefox_apply_autoconfig</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

###### Installation

Then run something like this:

```sh
mkdir -p "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/com.superuser.launchd/"
chmod u+x ./firefox_apply_autoconfig
mv ./firefox_apply_autoconfig "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/com.superuser.launchd/"

launchctl bootstrap "gui/$(launchctl manageruid)" ./com.superuser.firefox-apply-autoconfig.plist
```

###### Hammerspoon (Option 2)

###### init.lua

```lua
local function applyFirefoxAutoConfig()
  hs.task.new(
    os.getenv("HOME")
    ..
    "/.config/hammerspoon/scripts/firefox_apply_autoconfig",
    nil
  ):start()
end

local watcher = hs.pathwatcher.new(
  "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/",
  applyFirefoxAutoConfig
):start()

applyFirefoxAutoConfig()
```

##### Caveats

`general.config.sandbox_enabled` must be set to `false` (default value) in order for `ChromeUtils` to be defined in the autoconfig file. See [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1786785/how-to-hide-https-url-scheme-in-firefox-title-bar/1786786?noredirect=1#comment2814119_1786786).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: now removed
From Firefox support:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly :

> Note: You can customize keyboard shortcuts for Firefox using the https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/saka-key/ extension.

I hope it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this extension is not so practical. If it would work, this one: 
https://github.com/mikecrittenden/shortkeys would be nice. But it seems like, Firefox is allowing websites to suppress the bindings, which is super annoying when your bindings only work on a few sites :(

Comment: Fully agree, they need to find a good workaround to fix it

Comment: Keyboard shortcut documentation has nothing to do with changing keybindings.

Comment: Firefox documentation on key bindings doesn't invite to use the extension mentioned in the answer, or they stopped for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is now an outdated reply!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what kind of shortcuts you are after but there is a great extensions called [Vimium FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/?src=recommended) that allows you to browse completely mouseless. This extensions offers a filter mechanism that allows you to decide in which websites the keybindings should work.

It is still in experimental stage, since it is a port from a Chrome extensions but I am using and did encounter any bug or problem.

The bindings follow the VIM bindings and should be natural if you are already familiar with those, otherwise, you can custumize them to your own taste.

Answer (score 2):

[Benedikt's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1747680/181548) is very well written, but with one thing missing. The first line of `config.js` is ignored, starting on 1st line will eventually cause syntax error. So simply change it to something like this should do the trick.

```
// IMPORTANT: Start your code on the 2nd line
try {
...
```

This is mentioned in official document of AutoConfig and also https://github.com/xiaoxiaoflood/firefox-scripts, where the reddit post borrows idea from.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to change the shortcut **of an extension,** you can do so: https://support.mozilla.org/kb/manage-extension-shortcuts-firefox

> 1. Click the (hamburger) menu button, click ***Add-ons and themes*** and select ***Extensions***.
> 2. Click the ***Tools for all add-ons*** cogwheel.
> 3. Click ***Manage Extension Shortcuts*** in the menu.
>
> You will see the shortcut options (if available) for your installed add-ons.

[image: Screenshot for Manage Extension Shortcuts]