# disable firefox's control+w

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

How can firefox's keyboard shortcut control+W, which closes a tab, be disabled?  There's nothing in `about:config` under `browser.tabs`.

(When in a web session that is a virtual host's console, that's the venerable Linux keystroke to delete the last word you've typed.  Deleting not just a word but the entire console is astonishing.)

Firefox 112.0.1 on Ubuntu 22.

Regarding the answers to [Change key bindings (keyboard
shortcuts) in Firefox Quantum](https://superuser.com/questions/1271147/change-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-quantum):

- Errge's "patch firefox" answer fails in Ubuntu 22, because firefox
  is now in /snap which is a read-only filesystem, thus unpatchable.
- Benedikt's answer
  using autoconfig failed to disable Ctrl+W, with config.js
  `window.document.getElementById('key_close');`.  I don't know why.
- The other answers aren't for Linux.

Comment: This might be time to learn a new paradigm - Ctrl [or Cmd] W is universally accepted as 'Close Window'… in just about everything else.

Comment: This was addressed in https://superuser.com/questions/1271147/change-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-quantum . As @Tetsujin, states, however, currently Ctrl-W is used in *many* applications as the shortcut for closing tabs, -- Brave Browser, Kate, Okular, Notepad++, PDF XChange Editor, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change key bindings (keyboard shortcuts) in Firefox Quantum](https://superuser.com/questions/1271147/change-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-quantum)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik But those (non-browser) apps rarely wrap a bash shell, which is the only place I'm tempted to instinctively Ctrl+W.