# How to hide HTTPS URL scheme in Firefox title bar

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, user-interface

Right now Firefox shows the full URL in the title bar for visited sites. There is a [`browser.urlbar.trimURLs` preference in `about:config`](https://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Browser.) which  hides the `http://` prefix but not `https://`.  Other browsers like Safari and Chrome hide the `https://` prefix as well as `www.`. Is it possible to replicate this behavior in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add support for this in Firefox by including the following in a `firefox.cfg` (or equivalent) [AutoConfig file](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig):

```javascript
// -*- mode: javascript; -*- vim: set ft=javascript:
// See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig
"use strict";

(() => {
  if (Services.appinfo.inSafeMode) {
    return;
  }

  const addressPattern = new RegExp(
    "^(chrome:(?!//(global/content/commonDialog)\\.xhtml)|about:(?!blank))"
  );
  const hostnameStripPattern = new RegExp("^www\\.");

  Services.obs.addObserver(subject => {
    subject.addEventListener(
      "DOMContentLoaded",
      event => {
        const document = event.originalTarget;
        const window = document.defaultView;
        if (!addressPattern.test(window.location.href)) {
          return;
        }

        // Hide URL scheme once editing in URL bar is finished.
        const urlbarInput = document.getElementById("urlbar-input");
        const updateURLHandler = () => {
          if (!window.gURLBar.focused) {
            const untrimmedValue = urlbarInput.value;
            let url;
            try {
              url = new window.URL(untrimmedValue);
            } catch (error) {
              // Catch TypeError: URL constructor errors for invalid/partial URLs.
              if (error instanceof window.TypeError) {
                return;
              }
              throw error;
            }

            // Preserve existing behavior for built-in prefixes like "view-source:".
            if (url.protocol !== "https:" && url.protocol !== "http:") {
              return;
            }

            const suffix = url.pathname + url.search + url.hash;
            const displayValue =
              url.hostname.replace(hostnameStripPattern, "") +
                (suffix === "/" ? "" : suffix);

            if (displayValue !== urlbarInput.value) {
              window.gURLBar.value = displayValue;
              window.gURLBar._untrimmedValue = untrimmedValue;
            }
          }
        };

        urlbarInput?.addEventListener("SetURI", updateURLHandler);
        urlbarInput?.addEventListener("blur", updateURLHandler);
      },
      { once: true }
    );
  }, "chrome-document-global-created");
})();
```

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1785959/1802107) for additional context and installation instructions.

This will recreate Chrome's behavior, where the `https://[www.]` prefix is removed but the suffix is retained unless it's only a `/`. To use Safari's behavior (which removes the suffix entirely and only shows the domain), change `displayValue` to `url.hostname.replace(hostnameStripPattern, "")`.

You may also want to turn on the [`security.insecure_connection_text.enabled` preference](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/14/firefox-60-new-not-secure-indicator-preferences/) in `about:config` or `user.js` to show a "Not Secure" indicator in the URL bar for HTTP sites.

```javascript
user_pref("security.insecure_connection_text.enabled", true);
```

There's an open issue for this on Bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1067293).

**Update:** This is now officially supported in version 119 and above via the [`browser.urlbar.trimHttps` preference](https://ghacks.net/2023/09/19/firefox-119-will-launch-with-an-important-address-bar-change/).

```javascript
user_pref("browser.urlbar.trimHttps", true);
```

Comment: On Firefox 115 it doesn't work... Error in console: "ReferenceError: ChromeUtils is not defined [firefox.cfg:5:24]". 

Probably somehow related to this bug? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1766114

Comment: Turns out it works only if added "pref("general.config.sandbox_enabled", false)" in the prefs file

Comment: Thanks, added a note in the original post.

Comment: This script has a small problem — when url bar is focused, "https://" part is back, making it not possible, for example, to use double click to highlight any word in url. Other than that, it works great!