# How to change find bar "Whole Words" shortcut in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

On macOS, Firefox uses the control key for each of the keyboard shortcuts in the "Find in Page…" bar. For example, **Highlight All** is currently toggled by **Control-I**, **Match Case** is **Control-C**, **Match Diacritics** is **Control-I**, and **Whole Words** is **Control-W**. Unfortunately, this conflicts with my [Cocoa text system key binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html) (`DefaultKeyBinding.dict`) used in text views on macOS to delete the previous word.

```
{
    "^w" = "deleteWordBackward:";
}
```

Is there a way to change this shortcut so I can use **Control-W** to delete the previous word in the find bar?

Comment: Ctrl/W for delete should only be applicable in terminal-type applications, not regular text areas. It's Opt/delete everywhere else.

Comment: Oh, forgot this isn't the default. Updated the post with the relevant line from my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible via the [`ui.key.chromeAccess` preference](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Ui.key.chromeAccess) in `about:config` or `user.js`. For example, to change the prefix to **Control-Command**, use:

```javascript
user_pref("ui.key.chromeAccess", 10);
```

To disable it entirely, you can add the following to an AutoConfig file after the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```javascript
document.querySelector(".findbar-entire-word")?.removeAttribute("accesskey");
```

See [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1271147/change-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-quantum/1785959) for more details.