# Is it possible to modify/remove devtoolsKeyset key bindings in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been working on a locked-down version of Firefox and need to disable certain keyboard shortcuts. *Clarification: I'm the employee locking it down for my employer for use by our customers on a platform we own. I'm not trying to sidestep software security on a company- or school-owned platform.*
In the past I've done this by modifying the *omni.ja* file or by using extensions, but was trying to do this by following [Benedikt Köppel's instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1747680/1904713) on using Firefox's AutoConfig feature. It's working great with the key bindings listed under *mainKeyset*, but I'm so far unable to modify those listed under *devtoolsKeyset*.
I can see the *devtoolsKeyset* key bindings in the Browser Toolbox, but not when I check *view-source:chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml* (I suspect for security reasons)...which I imagine is the problem. But I wanted to see if this could still be done with AutoConfig.
Also, I know I can disable DevTools with a registry setting, but I can't guarantee registry permissions in the environments this browser will be used.
I would comment directly on Benedikt's post, but I just now created this account to ask this question and do not yet have the requisite reputation.

Comment: Is this software locked down by your employer or school, on a computer owned by them? Please better explain the reason for this client software being locked down. Also, re the other question: You ask your own questions in your own posts, you do not ask questions on other people's posts. Each person gets their own questions in their own posts.

Comment: I'm the employee locking it down for my employer for use by our customers on a platform we own. Many of our customers have web-based applications, but do not or aren't capable of supplying their own locked-down browser, so for many years we've been providing those customers a customized locked-down version of Firefox Portable ESR. We're using the portable version because software is not allowed to be installed directly on the shared workstations. The latest version I produced was FFP v78. Unfortunately, this version is now very old and our customers require a newer version.